# How to toggle class or trigger click event on last clicked element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a `<ul></ul>` with 4 `<li>` inside it.

```
<ul class="wcarchive-terms-list">
    <li class="wcarchive-term wcarchive-term-parent woof_term_224">
        <label class="wcarchive-term-label">
            <span class="wcarchive-list-opener wcarchive-list-close">
                Parent 1
            </span>
        </label>
    </li>

    <li class="wcarchive-term wcarchive-term-parent woof_term_294">
        <label class="wcarchive-term-label">
            <span class="wcarchive-list-opener wcarchive-list-close">
                Parent 2
            </span>
        </label>
    </li>

    <li class="wcarchive-term wcarchive-term-parent woof_term_274">
        <label class="wcarchive-term-label">
            <span class="wcarchive-list-opener wcarchive-list-close">
                Parent 3
            </span>
        </label>
    </li>

    <li class="wcarchive-term wcarchive-term-parent woof_term_284">
        <label class="wcarchive-term-label">
            <span class="wcarchive-list-opener wcarchive-list-close">
                Parent 4
            </span>
        </label>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Everytime I click a certain .wcarchive-term-label I am changing the class from `wcarchive-list-close` to `wcarchive-list-open`

```
  var j = jQuery.noConflict();
 j(document).on('click', '.wcarchive-terms-list .wcarchive-term-label', function(e) {
     j(this).find('.wcarchive-list-opener').toggleClass('wcarchive-list-close wcarchive-list-open');

 });
```

Do you know how can I toggle or trigger a click event when I want to click a new list?

For example: If I click `Parent 1` its `<span>` will now have a class of "wcarchive-list-open" and If I want to click `Parent 2` its `span class` should also change but but `Parent 1` should revert back to `<span class="wcarchive-list-close">`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: ```$('parentSelector').on('click', function(element){ $(element).find('childSelector').toggle(); })```


http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `open` class from all open elements and set it to `closed` when you do your click. Take a look at this small example:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.closed', function(e) {
  $('.open').removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
  $(this).toggleClass('closed').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.closed {
  background: red;
}

.open {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="closed"></div>

<div class="closed"></div>

<div class="closed"></div>
```